# What does "Don't disperse youself!" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

I encountered this expression in various texts. For example in this book [SelfBrand - The evolution: Turn yourself into an authentic brand!](https://books.google.ru/books?id=9OveDQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA142&ots=w1Tw1vOX-k&dq=%22Be%20specific%20about%20your%20branding%20proposal.%20Don%27t%20disperse%20yourself.%22&pg=PA142#v=onepage&q=%22Be%20specific%20about%20your%20branding%20proposal.%20Don't%20disperse%20yourself.%22&f=false), I found the following:

> "**One selling proposition**". Be specific about your branding proposal. ***Don't disperse yourself.*** After all, you've selected a specific target so you need to spread out a precise message. Otherwise, you'll confuse the ideas.

In this context, I think it is an analogous way of saying that one should not deal with too many topics. After all, *to disperse* means *to spread over a wide area/to go in different directions* by definition.

Could you tell me if that is correct? Thank you!

Comment: Link's not working. I wasn't sure where you wanted to send it, so I couldn't fix it.

Comment: In Britain, maybe elsewhere, we can say "Don't spread yourself too thin".

Comment: https://books.google.ru/books?id=9OveDQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA142&ots=w1Tw1vOX-k&dq=%22Be%20specific%20about%20your%20branding%20proposal.%20Don't%20disperse%20yourself.%22&pg=PA142#v=onepage&q=%22Be%20specific%20about%20your%20branding%20proposal.%20Don't%20disperse%20yourself.%22&f=false

Comment: What are these other texts where you've encountered "disperse yourself"?

Comment: Italian seems to be the native language of the author of that work. http://www.donatellarampado.com/chi-sono/

Comment: Yup, author is Italian - therefore I'd call it a poor translation rather than an actual idiom in current use.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: I found them [on Google](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22don%27t+disperse+yourself%22&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjU7qGzqJzdAhVRKewKHdv6DocQ_AUIECgB&biw=877&bih=388&dpr=2.19). I don't know if they all have the same meaning though.

Comment: Ordinarily the "self" is not something that can be **dispersed**.  That which is capable of being dispersed (dispersible) must be many in its composition (a crowd, for example, as I say in my answer, or air molecules). So it's a figurative usage that treats the self as "many", but not a figurative use that is at all common, hence my characterization of it as "idiosyncratic", peculiar to the author's concept of the branded self.

Comment: And I'm not talking about the self as having constituent elements or facets or faces, in the psychological sense, which is of course a commonplace, but about the verb **disperse** used either reflexively or transitively with **yourself** as object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is an idiosyncratic usage of the verb **disperse** and the sentences do not seem to have been written by a native speaker.  We **spread** messages; we do not "spread them *out*".  We **spread out** a bed sheet or a tablecloth or a picnic blanket or a large map.

When a crowd of people breaks up, and the individuals go their separate ways, the crowd is said to **disperse**.

> The crowd of protesters in front of City Hall has dispersed.

When a balloon is popped, the air inside the balloon **disperses**.

The word **yourself** refers, it seems, to your "brand identity".

The advice is, as you have surmised, to remain focused in the brand proposal and not to touch upon **diverse** (self-) branding strategies.

Comment: I'd like to know the reason for the downvote.

Comment: So would I. I think you're quite right that the text wasn't written by a native speaker, but perhaps someone thinks making that observation is "dismissive". Apart from the fact that ***disperse*** seems completely unsuitable for the context, there are several other aspects of the text that don't look at all "natural" to me. But [@Michael's](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/46805/michael-harvey) ***Don't spread yourself too thin*** seems right on the money here.